# php radio box values

Tags: php, radio-button

Given that when using an html radio box, to send values to a php script, only the selected values is sent to the php script, still holds true.

Do I still need to check that the user has selected something, when I am only interested in the selected value being sent to the php script, if the user does not select anything we do nothing or I guess I could prompt the user to select something.

If so, whats the best way to handle this with regards to radio boxes?

```
 <!--Using the radio box, a single selected value is sent to the php script for processing-->
    <td width="100px" height="30px">  
    <input type = "radio"
    name = "selection"
    value = "Lays" />Lays Chips 0.99c<br />

    <input type = "radio"
    name = "selection"
    value = "Ruffles" />Ruffles $1.85<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user will be able to click the "submit" button even without selecting an option from your radiobox.

If it's ok to send the form without a selection and you just want to do something different (or ignore it) when nothing is selected, you can do this:

```
<?php
  if (isset(($_POST['selection'])) {
    //Use it.. and make sure to validate user input.
  } else {
    //nothing was selected. Do something or just ignore?
  }
?>
```

OTOH, if you want to prevent submiting without a selection, you will need to use some JavaScript to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `radiobox` is not set, you can still post the form back to the server. Unless, of course, you have Javascript that prevents one from clicking on the submit form if the `radiobox` is not set.

So, you still need to check whether the `radiobox` is set or not, before working on it.